# SqlAlchemy 1.4 ORM - Correct Way to Select filtered by attribute .in_ 2nd selection

Tags: sqlalchemy

We recently updated sqlAlchemy to 1.4, where we use the ORM API.

```
def get_data(session, target_batch):
    in_scope_bar_ids = session.query(Bar.id).filter(Bar.batch_number == target_batch).subquery()

    query = (
        session.query(
            FooByBar.foo_id.label("FOO_ID"),
            FooByBar.bar_id.label("BAR_ID"),
        )
        .filter(FooByBar.bar_id.in_(in_scope_bar_ids))
    )

    df = pd.read_sql_query(query.selectable, session.get_bind())
    return df
```

Now triggers warning like:
`# SAWarning: Coercing Subquery object into a select() for use in IN(); please pass a select() construct explicitly .filter(FooByBar.bar_id.in_(in_scope_bar_ids))`

Dropping the `.subquery()` construct seems to fix it, but I can't find anything in the documentation explaining what changed. What's the proper, readable way to get a group of ids from table Bar and then filter FooByBar by those ids?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm suspecting this should be rewritten as a join, but since this type of query exists all over our code, I'm focused on why the behavior of the current code changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 1.4 docs for `subquery()`:

> A subquery is from a SQL perspective a parenthesized, named construct
> that can be placed in the FROM clause of another SELECT statement.

So I think the issue is that is not what you intended here.  You just want an unaliased, anonymous, subquery which is just a straight select.  Seems you can drop the `.subquery()` or start using `select()`.  I think another issue is that sqlalchemy has to assume you will return scalars and not something different.  Probably just backtracking some old implicit conversions from years ago that are now blocking progress to 2.0+.

There seems to be a little bit of background in this issue [3d99ee28ed368c3bdbeaf872ef65b0c9a7c0da33](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/commit/3d99ee28ed368c3bdbeaf872ef65b0c9a7c0da33)

*Examples*

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bars"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    batch_number = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foos"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class FooByBar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foos_bars'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foos.id'), nullable=False)
    bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bars.id'), nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def get_data(session, target_batch):
    in_scope_bar_ids = session.query(Bar.id).filter(Bar.batch_number == target_batch).subquery()

    query = (
        session.query(
            FooByBar.foo_id.label("FOO_ID"),
            FooByBar.bar_id.label("BAR_ID"),
        )
        .filter(FooByBar.bar_id.in_(in_scope_bar_ids))
    )

    query.all()

def get_data_no_subquery(session, target_batch):
    in_scope_bar_ids = session.query(Bar.id).filter(Bar.batch_number == target_batch)

    query = (
        session.query(
            FooByBar.foo_id.label("FOO_ID"),
            FooByBar.bar_id.label("BAR_ID"),
        )
        .filter(FooByBar.bar_id.in_(in_scope_bar_ids))
    )

    query.all()

def get_data_select(session, target_batch):
    in_scope_bar_ids = select(Bar.id).where(Bar.batch_number == target_batch)

    query = (
        session.query(
            FooByBar.foo_id.label("FOO_ID"),
            FooByBar.bar_id.label("BAR_ID"),
        )
        .filter(FooByBar.bar_id.in_(in_scope_bar_ids))
    )

    query.all()


with Session(engine) as session:
    b1 = Bar(batch_number=1)
    b2 = Bar(batch_number=2)
    session.add_all([b1, b2])
    f1 = Foo()
    f2 = Foo()
    session.add_all([f1, f2])
    session.flush()
    f1b1 = FooByBar(foo_id=f1.id, bar_id=b1.id)
    f2b2 = FooByBar(foo_id=f2.id, bar_id=b2.id)
    session.add_all([f1b1, f2b2])
    session.flush()

    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    # WARNING
    get_data(session, 1)

    get_data_no_subquery(session, 1)

    get_data_select(session, 1)
```

Comment: oh WOW, thank you. I was looking for something to make me feel better about our fix being the right one, but these examples are above and beyond. I appreciate it!